# Jquery how to stop auto load imges when parseHTML

Tags: jquery, image, load

I have a page using Jquery $.ajax to get another page's html code.
Here's what it looks like:

```
    <html><head>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    <!--
$(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:another_page_url,
            async:false,
            dataType:"text",
            success:function(doc){ 
                //do something with $(doc) 
                //e.g. alert($(doc).find('img').attr('src'));}
        });
});
    //-->
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre id="result" style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;"></pre>
    </body></html>
```

The another_page_url is a web page with lots of images like this:

```
<img src="http://ww3.sinaimg.cn/mw600/50cdeb22jw1e2a35t0w8ag.gif">
```

The problem is when I call $(doc) (equal to $.parseHTML(doc)) after success load, Jquery start ajax get requests to load all the images included in doc. My question is how to prevent this auto loading thing? I just want the image url string instead of these real images.

P.S. If I set dataType="xml" there will be a prase error.(Seems the page I want to load is not xml-compatible and I can't change it.) Set dataType="html" is equal to call $(doc) which lead me to the same situation.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: why not use json as a datatype?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Cuz the page I want to load is a large HTML page, I'm not sure how it would be by set dataType = 'json'.

Comment: @katsh I just got a prase error by set dataType='json', since the return data is a HTML content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for everyone. I got my question resolved like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url:url,
    async:false,
    dataType:"text",
    success:function(doc){ 
        var new_doc = doc.replace(/<img [^>]*src=['"]([^'"]+)[^>]*>/gi, function (match, capture) {return "<img no_load_src=\"" +capture+ "\" />";});
        parse_function(new_doc);
    },
    error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ alert(textStatus); }
});
```

Just two steps to solve this:

- Explicitly set dataType="text" in $.ajax call so jquery won't detect and parse the return
  html document.
- Use regex to replace all the img tag's src attribute before use it.(I change the <img attribute src="somewhere" /> to <img no_load_src="somewhere" /> to prevent jquery from load the real image.)

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you make request to load html data from it will also always be treated as html.
So if you want your html as string  then you need to replace  **<** with **&lt** and **>** with **&gt**

Please refer followings:

```
success:function(doc){ 

    // create dynamic temporary div
    var div = $("<div />" , { id : 'temp-container' });

    // appned reposne html into div 
    $(div).html(doc);


    var img_url = $(div).find('img').attr('src'); 

            // check firebug console
    console.log(img_url);   


}
```

You can find any attribute. There is no need top append it into body.
Hope it works fine for your. 
Good luck

Comment: Thanks for your advice but I don't really want plain html strings. I want to filter some <img src="whatever"> elements in $(doc), like this: var img_url = $(doc).find('img').attr('src'); But as soon as I call $(doc) my browser start to load all the images in doc.

Comment: You mean to say you want an array of image source from html nothing else.

Comment: Yes just source URLs and some other attribute values. String based parse would be a tough task so that's why I need $(doc).